# Why can "a*a+" and "(a{2,3})*a{2,3}" match "aaaa" while "(a{2,3})*" cannot?

Tags: regex

My understanding of `*` is that it consumes as many characters as possible (greedily) but "gives back" when necessary. Therefore, in `a*a+`, `a*` would give one (or maybe more?) character back to `a+` so it can match.

However, in `(a{2,3})*`, why doesn't the first "instance" of `a{2,3}` gives a character to the second "instance" so the second one can match?

Also, in `(a{2,3})*a{2,3}` the first part does seem to give a character to the second part.

Comment: What do you mean by *cannot*? It [can](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=b%28a%7b2%2c3%7d%29*b&i=baaaab).

Comment: This should be tagged with whichever regex flavour you're using.

Comment: It certainly matches - check it here: https://regex101.com/r/jOT0f7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround for your question is to match `aaaa` with regex `^(a{2,3})*$`.

Your problem is that:

> In the case of `(a{2,3})*`, regex doesn't seem to consume as much
>   character as possible.

I suggest not to think in giving back characters. Instead, the key is **acceptance**.

Once regex **accept** your string, the matching will be over. The pattern `a{2,3}` only matches `aa` or `aaa`. So in the case of matching `aaaa` with `(a{2,3})*`, the greedy engine would match `aaa`. And then, it can't match more `a{2,3}` because there is only one `a` remained. Though it's able for regex engine to do backtrack and match an extra `a{2,3}`, it wouldn't. `aaa` is now **accepted** by the regex, thus regex engine would not do expensive backtracking.

If you add an `$` to the end of the regex, it simply tells regex engine that a partly match is unacceptable. Moreover, it's easy to explain the `(a{2,3})*a{2,3}` case with accepting and backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is this:

> My understanding of * is that it consumes as many characters as possible (greedily) but "gives back" when necessary

This is completely wrong. It is not what greedy means.

Greedy simply means "use the longest possible match". It does not give anything back.

Once you interpret the expressions with this new understanding everything makes sense.

---

1. `a*a+` - zero or more `a` followed by one or more `a`
2. `(a{2,3})*a{2,3}` - zero or more of either two or three `a` followed by either two or three `a` (note: the KEY THING to remember is "zero or more", the first part not matching any character is considered a match)
3. `(a{2,3})*` - zero or more of either two or three `a` (this means that after matching three `a`s the last single `a` left cannot match)

Comment: If this is the case, why does `a*a+` match `aaaa`? `a*` would have consumed all the four characters, leaving `a+` zero character.

Comment: `a*` means zero or more a therefore it can match nothing, `a`, `aa`, `aaa` and `aaaa`. That's why it works. On the other hand `(a{2,3})*` means match zero or more of either two `a` or three `a`. Therefore it can only match nothing, `aa` and `aaa`. Note that in neither case does `*` give anything back. Don't think in terms of giving back, think instead in terms of if/else

Comment: @sqd It's backtracking.

Comment: @iBug: Technically backtracking is not necessary in these cases. Since we're not matching capture groups we can compile the regexp into simple state machines

Answer (score 0):

backtracking is done only if match fails however `aaa` is a valid match, a negative lookahead `(?!a)` can be use to prevent the match be followed by a `a`.

[compare](https://regex101.com/r/eA5jB2/159)

```
(aaa?)*
```

and

```
(aaa?)*(?!a)
```